Problem loading SVG in Storybook + Vite + React
I have this configuration of storybook:


const config: StorybookConfig = {
    stories: ["../stories/**/*.stories.tsx"],
    framework: "@storybook/react-vite",
    core: {
        builder: "@storybook/builder-vite",
    },
    addons: [
        "@storybook/addon-links",
        "@storybook/addon-a11y",
        "@storybook/addon-essentials",
        "@storybook/preset-scss",
        {
            name: "@storybook/addon-storysource",
            options: {
                parser: "typescript",
            },
        },
    ],
    docs: {},
};



And my vite.config.mts looks like this


import path from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";
import eslint from "vite-plugin-eslint";

export default defineConfig({
    base: "./",
    plugins: [
        react(),
        eslint({
            exclude: ["node_modules/**"],
        }),
        svgr({
            include: ["**/*.svg"],
        }),
    ],
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                api: "modern-compiler",
                silenceDeprecations: ["legacy-js-api", "mixed-decls", "color-functions", "import", "global-builtin"],
            },
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            screens: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/screens"),
            "~bootstrap": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/bootstrap"),
            "~react-datepicker": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react-datepicker"),
        },
    },
});



when I try to do something like:
import SVG from "folder/to/file.svg"

... some component
    <img src={SVG} />

the image is not shown and I can see a 404 networking error doing:
GET http://localhost:64724/(props)%20=%3E%20/*%20@__PURE__%20*/%20React.createElement(%22svg%22,%20%7B%20id:%20%22Livello_2%22,%20%22data-name%22:%20%22Livello%202%22,%20xmlns:%20%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22,%20viewBox:%20%220%200%2030.377672115397218%2034.345035318867303%22,%20style:%20%7B%7D,%20...props%20%7D,%20/*%20@__PURE__%20*/%20React.createElement(%22defs%22,%20null,%20/*%20@__PURE__%20*/%20React.createElement(%22style%22,%20null,%20%22/n%20%20%20%20%20%20.cls-1%20%7B/n%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fill:%20none;/n%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20stroke:%20 

Before with Storybook + webpack this worked correctly.
Here are my lib versions:

storybook 8.4.7
vite-plugin-svgr 4.3.0
react 18.3.1

Thanks for the help
